# Setting current date in redux initial state

Tags: javascript, redux

Quick question:

If I wanted my app to initialise with some representation of the current date stored in the state, is it acceptable under Redux to do something like this:

```
import Moment from 'moment';
const initialMoment = Moment();

const initialState = fromJS({
  month_year: [initialMoment.format("MM"), initialMoment.format("YYYY")]
});
```

I am aware that reducers themselves should be pure and not call impure functions such as Date.now(), but is it ok to pass in an initial state that is the result of another function call as above, or would it be better to initialise with empty state, e.g.:

```
const initialState = fromJS({
  month_year: []
});
```

Comment: Your initial state is not actually part of your reducer really. As long as your reducer itself stays pure, I don't see anything wrong with this.